# How can i delete something from an array using php and without sql

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

I have a user list on my home page with a delete button besides every user, I need to link each button with the right user to delete.

```
<form action="http://localhost:8000/?f=delete_Users" method="POST">
            <?php
            include_once INCLUDE_PATH . '/Services/user_service.php';
            $currentUserList = json_decode(file_get_contents('./Data/users.json'), true);
                    foreach ($currentUserList as $key => $value) :
            ?> <li><?php echo ($value['username']) ?>
                    <input type="submit" name="deleteBtn" value="Deletar">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value= "<?php echo ($key) ?>">
                   <?php
```

After this, i need to link the right user to the delete function but what i've tried so far hasn't worked.

```
function delete_Users($_POST) {
     print_r($_POST);
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    include_once INCLUDE_PATH . '/Services/user_service.php';
            $currentUserList = list_Users();
        
    if (isset($_POST['deleteBtn'])) {
        array_splice($currentUserList, $id, 1);
    };
}
```

Comment: What does your `print_r($_POST)` give you? What does `list_Users()` do? Why are you doing an `array_splice` but throwing away the return value? Do you have a function somewhere that you haven't shown for updating the users file?

Comment: You could wrap a form around each row in your list of users, so that when you submit the form it only sends the single hidden id to the url. You can also generally put the users ID in the value of the button that's clicked, but nothing wrong with a hidden input field. Assuming your <li>'s are a child of <ul>, you'd probably have to put the forms inside of each <li></li>

Comment: Nothing wrong with a hidden field if you want to create a separate form for each user - but if you use only one form, then submitting that will submit _all_ the hidden fields. I'd really much rather use a submit `button` here - then you can put the ID of the record to delete as the value of that button. And clicking that button will _only_ send the value of that button, and not the other buttons.

Comment: I see, making a button isn't a bad idea really.  Joel gave me a nice idea with wrapping the form around each row. Thanks for the help guys!